# Print out strings from an arraylist in a given range java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

My method is supposed to print out all of the strings in between 2 strings in my ArrayList, exclusive of both the beginning string and the end string.

```
public void printRange(String beg, String end)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {

    }
}
```

String beg is the beginning string and String end is the last string. To further clear up, if I have an ArrayList containing the words "dog" "cat" "apple" "banana" "turtle", and I enter in "cat" and "turtle", the method should print out "apple" and "banana".

I know I should iterate through the list, but I'm lost as to where I go from there.

Edit: Sorry for posting 2 questions! I'll submit them differently next time.

Comment: *I have 2 unrelated questions.* - Please post separate questions..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is actually two separate questions.

Comment: @AlexisKing -I don't think closing this question because it contains 2 different questions is right. I was merely pointing out that the it will be easy for the OP to get answers if he posts 2 separate questions

Answer (score 2):

Try using a flag to avoid one more N iteration.

```
 public void printRange(String beg, String end)
    {
        boolean startPrinting = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (startPrinting) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }
            if (list.get(i).equals(beg)) {
                startPrinting = true;
            } else if (list.get(i).equals(end)) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted, but beg should be left out. So you might want to shift the printing block upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would edit out the second question. You don't post two questions for one topic on SO.

Regarding your first question, you want to get the index of where the first string and the last string are found. Something like this:

```
public void printRange(String beg, String end)
 {
    int begIdx, endIdx;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if (list[i].equals(beg)) {
            begIdx = i;
        }
        if (list[i].equals(end)) {
            endIdx = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i = begIdx; i < endIdx; i++)
        // Print range...
}
```

That's a quick and dirty implementation. You can do this in one traversal of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tiny state machine -

- state 0 = beginning not found
- state 1 = beginning found, end not found
- state 2 = end found (or could go back to 0 if you want to look for beginning again)

You need relevant checks to change the state and only have to print stuff out when you're in state 1.

This way you only have to go through the list once instead of going through it (partially) to find beginning and end, and then going through it (partially) again to output required fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the indexOf() method. I am not sure what you are up to, but bear in mind a List can contain duplicate keys. Consider using a Set instead.

package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

{
    list.add("dog");
    list.add("cat");
    list.add("apple");
    list.add("banana");
    list.add("turtle");
}

public void printRange(String beg, String end)
{
    int start = list.indexOf(beg) + 1;
    int finish = list.indexOf(end);

    if (start <= 0 || start >= finish) return;

    for(int i = start; i < finish; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().printRange("cat", "turtle");
}
```

}